# How can I pass column names to tidyr::complete

Tags: r, tidyr

How do I use `tidyr::complete` to add additional rows to a data frame, specifying the column names wanted as an input, rather than having to hard code them?

```
df <- data.frame(
 group = c(1:2, 1),
 item_id = c(1:2, 2),
 item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
 value1 = 1:3,
 value2 = 4:6
)
```

This works:

```
df %>% tidyr::complete(group, item_id, item_name)
```

but to avoid hardcoding I ideally want this to work:

```
cols_wanted <- c("group", "item_id", "item_name")
df %>% tidyr::complete(cols_wanted)
```

But it returns the following error:

```
Error in `dplyr::full_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `cols_wanted`.
Traceback:

1. df %>% tidyr::complete(cols_wanted)
2. tidyr::complete(., cols_wanted)
3. complete.data.frame(., cols_wanted)
4. dplyr::full_join(out, data, by = names)
5. full_join.data.frame(out, data, by = names)
6. join_mutate(x, y, by = by, type = "full", suffix = suffix, na_matches = na_matches, 
 .     keep = keep)
7. join_cols(tbl_vars(x), tbl_vars(y), by = by, suffix = suffix, 
 .     keep = keep, error_call = error_call)
8. standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names, 
 .     error_call = error_call)
9. check_join_vars(by$y, y_names, error_call = error_call)
10. abort(bullets, call = error_call)
11. signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

My current solution is:

```
eval(parse(text = paste("df %>% tidyr::complete(",
                   paste(noquote(cols_wanted), collapse = ", "),
                   ")")))
```

But I would like a solution that doesn't use eval or parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!!!syms` with the vector of column names, where `syms` turns the strings into a list of symbols, then we use the unquote-splice operator, `!!!`, which passes the list of arguments to `complete`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   complete(!!!syms(cols_wanted))
```

**Output**

```
  group item_id item_name value1 value2
  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      <int>  <int>
1     1       1 a              1      4
2     1       1 b             NA     NA
3     1       2 a             NA     NA
4     1       2 b              3      6
5     2       1 a             NA     NA
6     2       1 b             NA     NA
7     2       2 a             NA     NA
8     2       2 b              2      5
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation or at the very least a link to one for OP? It’s otherwise hard to impossible to understand how/why this works, or to find more information. `syms` also isn’t attached by default.

Comment: For what it's worth, this style of answering, whilst relatively common, is definitely frowned upon (search meta for "fastest gun in the West").